# Android bluetooth connection with bluetooth rs232 adapter

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I've been planning to make an Android App, that would communicate with this bluetooth rs232 adapter

http://www.nordfield.com/wireless-serial-rs232-bluetooth-adapter

and I'm not sure what should I do with UUID in this case? Will I be able to start a connection with an application, that would look like BluetoothChat sample app from Google?

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat/

Comment: Ever get something to work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've solved the problem already. Actually there is possibility to create Bluetooth connection without knowing device's UUID. It is achieved by this code:

```
public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        try {               
            Method method;

            method = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class } );
            tmp = (BluetoothSocket) method.invoke(device, 1);  

        } catch (Exception e) { }

        mmSocket = tmp;
    }
```

All of the rest of connection management is done the same as in BluetoothChat sample app from Google.